# Shouldn't setting onsubmit to "false" prevent the form's action being realized?

Tags: javascript, html

I understand that it's common practice to call a validateRequiredFields() function which returns a boolean for the onsubmit value, as illustrated in the code below:

```
<form method="post" action="myPage.php" onsubmit="validateRequiredFields()">
```

Before implementing such a function, I've tried out the following code as a simple test to see whether it will keep me on the same page rather than redirecting me to myPage.php. However, I am being redirected nonetheless.

```
<form method="post" action="myPage.php" onsubmit="return false">
```

Comment: `return false;` should be at the bottom of your unexecude `validateRequiredFields` function.

Comment: [It works for me.](https://jsfiddle.net/2vksbehc/)

Comment: Do you have any javascript errors in your console? That _might_ stop the `return false` from stopping the submission.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this and see if it helps.
Please add `return false;` at the bottom of the function or

```
onsubmit="return false;"
```

Try putting the `;` at the end.